# How to Pass data from Flexcard to call API

Tags: api, cpq, vlocity, omnistudio

I was doing scenario using flexcard, the scenario is to display Order line items in flexcard with a configure button to update product attributes. I have displayed products in flexcard.Now, I have to configure the attributes, for that I have to pass the values changed to putCartsItems api upon clicking the submit button, I am kind of not getting an idea on how to pass the updated values to the IP/api. Would be really helpful if someone can share their thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.[image]